# Ajax call with DB Connection 'include' gives POST 500 error

Tags: php, ajax, database, post, connection

Does anyone know why when I move a database connection 'include' out of a function and place it at the beginning of the PHP file that I get a POST 500 error? The exact same database connection 'include' works perfectly **within** the function. Here is the code that causes the error:

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/phpscripts/set_path.php'); // DB Connection Path
include 'mysqli_connect_sa.php'; // DB Connection

if(isset($_POST['row'])) 
{
    $uid = $_POST['row'];
    $response_bdls = getBDLs($uid);
    $response_cg = getCompetencyGaps($uid);
    echo json_encode(array($response_bdls, $response_cg));
}
```

Just in case you want to see the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/phpscripts/ss_scbdls.php',  // 
            data: {row : row},
            success:(function(response){
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                loadSC_bdls(response[0]);
                loadSC_cg(response[1]);
            })
        });
```

Thank you for any insights or direction you can provide.

**Requested Information #1**

Here is the mysqli_connect_sa.php Content:

```
// SA Database access information
    $hn = 'localhost';
    $db = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $un = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $pw = 'xxxxxxxx';

    // Connect to DB
    $dbc = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
    
    // Set the Encoding
    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8mb4');
```

Function:

```
function getBDLs($candidate_id)
{
    $sc_bdls = [];

    $sql_query_bdls = "SELECT bdl_increment AS id, learn_load, start_date, target_date, completed_date, bdl_20, bdl_10, bdl_70, cg, cg_orn, cg_tit, cg_lj FROM bdls INNER JOIN competency_gaps USING (cg_id) WHERE bdls.candidate_id = $candidate_id";
    $result_bdls = $dbc->query($sql_query_bdls);

    while($bdls = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_bdls)) {
        $sc_bdls[] = $bdls;
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result_bdls);
    return $sc_bdls;
}
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Please include the "function" and the contents of mysqli_connect_sa.php. Most likely you are defining a variable in the php file that you are trying to access in the function. btw, mysqli is deprecated, you should use PDO, which makes the coding a lot more specific which in turn makes it easier to debug.

Comment: Other than the four authentication parameters, all the mysqli_connect_sa.php file contains is $dbc = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db); The function is function getBDLs($candidate_id)
{
 $sc_bdls = [];

 $sql_query_bdls = "SELECT bdl_increment AS id, bdl_70, cg, cg_orn, cg_tit, cg_lj FROM bdls INNER JOIN competency_gaps USING (cg_id) WHERE bdls.candidate_id = $candidate_id";
 $result_bdls = $dbc->query($sql_query_bdls);

 while($bdls = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_bdls)) {
  $sc_bdls[] = $bdls;
 }

 mysqli_free_result($result_bdls);
 return $sc_bdls;
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Of course ... done! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: `$dbc` no longer exists within the scope of the function. You'll need to pass it in. Please read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Okay ... I see now what is happening. Thank you. If you want to provide as an answer, I will select this to close the question. Again, very much appreciated.